# What's the proper way to name CSS selectors. It seems inconsistent how it works

Tags: asp.net, css

I applied a style to a buttonfield in a details view called `ProductDetailsEditButton`.  I thought the name of the selector would thus be `td .ProductDetailsEditButton` but this didn't work.  However, when I called it `td.ProductDetailsEditButton` (without the space), it did work.

Does there have to be a space between the two or not?  Is that always the case or does it depend?  Sorry, but it seems inconsistent in the naming convention and I want to know what I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is a space it means that the selector will match child elements of a `<td>` that have `class="ProductDetailsEditButton"`. For example:

```
<td>
    <div class="ProductDetailsEditButton">Button</div>
</td>
```

When there is no space it will match `<td class="ProductDetailsEditButton">`.

Comment: What if I instead inserted a button in a `<td>` and applied the css class directly to that button? Would I also do `td.ProductDetailsEditButton` or would it be something like `td input.ProductDetailsEditButton`?

Comment: @TheVanillaThrilla, you could simply use `.ProductDetailsEditButton`. It will match all elements with this class. If you want to be more specific you could do `td input.ProductDetailsEditButton` assuming `<td><input type="button" class="ProductDetailsEditButton" value="Hello" /></td>`

Answer (score 5):

These are two separate things:

```
td .ProductDetailsEditButton
```

means "an element with the class `ProductDetailsEditButton` that is a child of a `td`"

```
td.ProductDetailsEditButton
```

means "a `td` element with the class `ProductDetailsEditButton`"

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification.  Obviously I'm still learning CSS and have much to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

well in your selector you are referring to a "td", is you class set on the actual button element or is it set on the parent td container?  If it is set on your button and only that button you would be able to reference it in your css using

```
 input.ProductDetailsEditButton
```

if you wanted to be very specific or simply

```
 .ProductDetailsEditButton
```

if it can be applied to many more elements other than the button

Answer (score 0):

When you use a space in between `td .ProductDetailsEditButton` you say give me the ProductDetailsEditButton that is child of a td.

When you write it without a space `td.ProductDetailsEditButton` you say give me the td that has the class ProductDetailsEditButton.